# Sprinklers pattern for a trivial rectangular plot (27' x 34')

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a rectangular patch of lawn 27' x 34'.
What is the correct placement of sprinkler heads for such a shape?
I would like to use Hunter MP rotators.
Rainbird online design tool suggested putting 4 heads in the corners (see the image), but that doesn't seem to provide uniform coverage.

The local sprinkler shop asks for $75 design fee plus wants to sell me the materials (50% more expensive than other places). I was expecting that something so trivial should be easily googleable, but I couldn't find anything.

(I can figure out pipes layout, water flow, pipe sizes, zones, etc. on my own)

[image]

Comment: Coverage won't be "uniform" with any sprinkler. Round patterns, rectangular area. Xeriscaping or vegetable/flower beds and drip irrigation, or Astroturf...

Comment: You seem to be fixated on a specific brand and type of sprinkler head, which is preventing a full "double coverage" scheme. Have you considered 1/2 circle pop-ups in the middle of the perimeter? IMO a diminishing strip that only gets single coverage, a foot across at its widest,  isn't going to be a problem anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Not enough sprinklers.

I have assisted in installing MP Rotators. But we only used them because of the low flow rate so an isolated garden could be watered using just one zone (and so only one solenoid valve etc).

The MP Rotators are very pretty to look at when running.

The designer would almost certainly ask for popups. The minimum would be Four along each long edge, and three interleaved down the middle. With 15’ nozzles. Probably broken into three zones.

Or gear drives might be used, which also popup and then rotate. These throw further. The Hunter ones seem to give a more uniform coverage than the Rainbird ones (which tend to water mostly in a ring).

The furtherest I have seen these was 23’ (7 metres) apart. So one at each corner will give some overlap.